# Matplotlib custom colors in scatter plot

Tags: python, matplotlib

I would like to know if there is some elegant way to set discrete colors in a scatter plot based on the value of the entry.
For a completly simplified example:

```
x=np.arange(100)
plt.scatter(x,x,c=x,cmap='jet')
plt.show()
```

[image]

So let's say I want all values lower than 40 green, those between 40 and 60 green, and those larger than 60 to be red.
I know that I could create a loop with some if statements that generates a list based on those conditions, so that I have something like `colorlist=['blue','blue',.....]`.

[image]
I know that this works, but is there some different way of doing it, or is this the easiest way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.colors as mcol

cmap = mcol.ListedColormap(["blue","green","red"])

bounds = [0, 40, 60, 100]
norm = mcol.BoundaryNorm(bounds, cmap.N)

x=np.arange(100)
plt.scatter(x,x,c=x,cmap=cmap,norm=norm)
plt.show()
```

[image]

For further details, take a look [here](https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/colors/colorbar_only.html#discrete-intervals-colorbar):